# How to set up a zf2 form for a ManyToOne doctrine mapping

Tags: forms, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, many-to-one

I'm having trouble hydrating a form in zf2 using a doctrine ManyToOne unidirectional relationship.  My entities look like this:

```
namespace AdminMyPages\Entity;

class MyPageItem
{
    // ... 

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyMessage")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="myMessageID", referencedColumnName="myMessageID")
     **/
    private $myMessage;

    // ... 

    /**
     * Set MyMessage
     *
     * @param Collection $myMessage
     */
    public function setMyMessage(Collection $myMessage = null)
    {
        $this->myMessage = $myMessage;
    }

    /**
     * Get MyMessage
     * 
     * @return myMessage
     */
    public function getMyMessage()
    {
        return $this->myMessage;
    }

}

class MyMessage
{
    // ... 
}
```

The fieldset for `MyPageItemFieldset` looks like this:

```
namespace AdminMyPages\Form;

class MyPageItemFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('mypage-item-fieldset');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'AdminMyPages\Entity\MyPageItem'))
             ->setObject(new MyPageItem());

        // ...

        $myMessageFieldset = new MyMessageFieldset($objectManager);

    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {

        // ...

        return array(
            'myMessage' => array(
                'required' => false
            ),
        );

    }

}
```

The fieldset for `MyMessageFieldset` looks like this:

```
namespace AdminMyPages\Form;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

use AdminMyPages\Entity\MyMessage;

class MyMessageFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('mypage-message-fieldset');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'AdminMyPages\Entity\MyMessage'))
             ->setObject(new MyMessage());

        // ...

        'name' => 'myMessageText',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Textarea',
            'attributes' => array(
                //'type'  => 'textarea',
                'rows'  => 10,
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'text',
            ),
        ));

        // ...

    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {

        // ...

        return array(
            'myMessageText' => array(
                'required' => false
            ),
        );

        // ...

    }


}
```

in my controller I have:

```
    $myPageItem = $this->getEntityManager()->find('AdminMyPages\Entity\MyPageItem', $mypageitemID);

    $form = new EditMyPageItemForm($objectManager);
    $form->setBindOnValidate(false);
    $form->bind($myPageItem);
```

With this configuration I am able to "get" data from the `MyMessage` through `getMyMessage()`, so I know that the tables have been joined.  I can bind the entity in a form and use the form elements from the MyPageItemFieldset.  However, I am not able to use form elements from the MyMessageFieldset.  I don't know if my problem is in how I've got the fieldset files written or if it is in how I am trying to call the form elements.  Here are some trials I've made in the edit view:

```
// this gets the message text that can be displayed in the view:
$myMessageText = $myPageItem->getMyMessage()->getMyMessageText();

// this allows me to get a form element from the MyPageItemFieldset:
$pifs=$form->get('mypage-item-fieldset');
$myPageItemOwner = $pifs->get('myPageItemOwner');

// these are some trails for getting a form element from the MyMessageFieldset:
$mfs_1 = $pifs;
$mfs_2 = $pifs->get('myMessageFieldset');
$mfs_3 = $pifs->get('');
$mfs_4a = $pifs->get('myMessageFieldset')->getFieldsets();
$mfs_4b = $mfs_4a[0];
$mfs_5 = $pifs->$myMessageFieldset->get('mypage-message-fieldset');

    $myMessageText = $mfs_1->get('myMessamypage-message-fieldsetgeText');
    // No element by the name of [myMessageText] found in form

    $myMessageText = $mfs_2->get('myMessageText');
    // No element by the name of [myMessageFieldset] found in form

    $myMessageText = $mfs_3->get('myMessageText');
    // No element by the name of [mypage-message-fieldset] found in form

    $myMessageText = $mfs_4b->get('myMessageText');
    // No element by the name of [myMessageFieldset] found in form  

    $myMessageText = $mfs_5->get('myMessageText');
    // Notice: Undefined variable: myMessageFieldset in  ... \edit.phtml ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the [DoctrineModule Hydrator documentation](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md#example-2--onetoonemanytoone-associations)?  It's a bit misplaced IMO (related to DoctrineORMModule but stored in DoctrineModule) so I wouldn't be surprised if you hadn't.  That section contains a full example of building complete Form infrastructure for an entity with a ManyToOne association.